# Is water thermolysis via microwave heating feasible?

Tags: water, physical-chemistry, microwaves

Can water molecules be heated enough (2500°C? 3000°C?) to be separated into hydrogen and oxygen by thermolysis via a microwave emitter?

I've searched around but it appears this hasn't been researched? So I'm guessing it's either a very inefficient process that hasn't been given any thought, or it has been tried and not proven useful.

I believe there should be many different approaches to how to achieve this (eg. a very small water amount put inside an EM resonating chamber with a magnetron attached), but I wonder if there's any limiting factor why there would be a top temperature achievable by microwave heating of water (eg: how does the heating effect vary according to the water sample's phase/pressure-temperature).

Comment: You would get a high temperature mixture of oxygen and hydrogen ions, which would convert back to water when the temperature dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern chemical theory we deal with *Chemical Equilibria*. In the case of the decomposition of water:

$$\text{H}_2\text{O}(g) \leftrightarrows \text{H}_2(g)+\frac12 \text{O}_2(g)$$

We define an *Equilibrium Constant* $K$:
$$K=\frac{[\text{H}_2]\times[\text{O}_2]}{[\text{H}_2\text{O}]}$$

where the bracketed quantities are concentrations.

Nernst teaches us that:

$$\Delta G=-RT\ln K\tag{1}$$

where $\Delta G$ is the change in *Gibbs Free Energy* (left to right).

But from $(1)$ we glean that:

$$K=\exp{\left(-\frac{\Delta G}{RT}\right)}\tag{2}$$

[This reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Gibbs_free_energy_of_formation) gives the Standard Giggs Free Energy of the Decomposition of water as:

$$\Delta G=+229\,\mathrm{kJ/mol}$$

This being $> 0$ , the value for $K$ will be $\ll 1$ and the values for $[\text{H}_2]$ and $[\text{O}_2]$ very small.

From $(2)$ can be gleaned that as $T$ increases, $K$ becomes larger (assuming $\Delta G$ in temperature invariant, which is not $100 \,\text{%}$ true) and the concentrations on the Right hand side also increase (as expected).

**However**, this is not a practical way of splitting water into hydrogen and oxygen because the moment you lower the temperature again, the equilibrium 'shifts back' to the left and the hydrogen and oxygen **recombine** to water.

The only way to avoid this recombination would be to **physically separate** the hydrogen and oxygen at the thermolysis high temperature. There are some well-known thermochemistry systems that rely on that method but thermolysis of water just isn't one of them.

Comment: I see. I guess I'm trying to shoehorn a few sci-fi-ish hypothesis I've got into my poor understanding of high-energy particle physics. I'm trying to come up with a way to "instantly" turn a (small) volume of water into an ignitable mix of H and O (regardless of inefficiency of the input energy required), but most methods I try reading/asking about end up with a plasma state that does not appear to be combustable.

Comment: A 'plasma state' implies a gas at very high temperature (like $>20000\,\mathrm{K}$ or so) At such temperatures dissociation of water into hydrogen and oxygen is 'complete'. But this plasma isn't combustible. Lowering its temperature leads to reconstitution of the water. Thanks for accepting!

Comment: Can't plasma state be achieved by adding (a large) electrical charge too, though?

Comment: Also, when you say "reconstitution of water", do you mean it'd spontaneously combust when temperature lowers enough? Or water would form without any further heat being released?

Comment: You could call it combustion, I suppose. The heat to decompose water (say per mol) is EXACTLY the same as the heat of reaction (hy. + ox. = water). You bet back EXACTLY what you put in. Conservation of energy.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I'd expected you'd need more energy to break up the bond than released upon combustion.